# Grouping Linq Issue, can't get it right

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Emp
{
     public int EmpId { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public List<string> Email { get; set; }             
}
```

I fetch data from database and put it in a list

```
List<Emp> employees= new List<Emp>();
// fill the list here via DB call
```

The list would have, please also note that Type field would always be same for same user but email would be different

```
employees[0] = new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Email = "one@test.com" }; 
employees[1] = new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type= "User", Email = "two@test.com"     }; 

employees[2] = new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test", Email = "three@test.com" }; 
employees[3] = new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type= "Test", Email = "four@test.com"}; 

employees[4] = new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test", Email = "five@test.com" }; 
employees[5] = new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type= "Test", Email = "six@test.com"}; 

employees[6] = new Emp{ EmpId = 4, Type= "User", Email = "seven@test.com"};
```

I'm trying to group Emp based on their EmpId
so the result should be a new list

**Expected Result**

```
Result = new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Email = "one@test.com", "two@test.com" }; 
     new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test", Email = "three@test.com", "four@test.com" }; 
     new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test", Email = "five@test.com", "six@test.com" }; 
     new Emp{ EmpId = 4, Type = "User", Email = ""seven@test.com" };
```

//This is what I have done so far
// Please let me know if this is incorrect

```
var result = from emp in employees
              group emp.Email by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into g
              select new { Key = g.Key, Type = g.Key.Type, Emails = g.ToList() };
```

// My problem comes here when I loop this result

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
Console.WriteLine(r.Key.EmpId + "--" + r.Key.Type);

//This is where I need to get all emails of the Employee which I grouped 
// iF I IMPLEMENT FOREACH
    foreach (var e in r.Emails)
    {
        //?? WHAT i DO HERE 
        //e.?? to get email
    }

// OR  iF I IMPLEMENT FOR LOOP

    for(int i = 0 ; i< r.Emails.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner Loop" + "--" + r.Key.EmpId + "--" + r.Key.Type + "--" + r.Emails[0].ToString()); // r.Emails[0].ToString() prints out System.Collections.Generic.List '1[System.String]
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I mad eany mistake or there's other way to do this.
**All I need is Group employees based on EmpID and also have their Type but grouped Emails.**

Comment: you are adding a string when the emp object is expecting a list<string> in the email property

Answer (score 1):

Your `group emp.Email by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type }` means that each element of the group will have a key of the anonymous type, and an "element type" of `List<string>`. You're then propagating that element type using `Emails = g.ToList()` in your `select` clause. Therefore I'd expect the type of `r.Emails` to be `List<List<string>>` (which you should be able to validate in Visual Studio by hovering over `r.Emails`.

You *could* handle that in your loop - or you could just flatten it in your `select` call, creating a new `Emp`:

```
select new Emp {
    EmpId = g.Key.EmpId,
    Type = g.Key.Type,
    Emails = g.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()
};
```

Here the `SelectMany` call is just flattening the "sequence of lists" to a single sequence.

Comment: Many Thanks Jon Skeet. Yup, you are right, r.Emails is indeed List<List<string>>. My problem is even if I do SelectMany, but then how do I loop through to get all emails for that employee. I understand that there would be two loops. If I change the code now 
 var result = from emp in employees
              group emp.Email by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into g
              //select new { Key = g.Key, Type = g.Key.Type, Emails = g.ToList() };
  select new Emp{ EmpId = g.Key.EmpId, Type = g.Key.Type, Email = g.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList() };

Comment: @sky: No, there wouldn't be two loops. With my code, the result is exactly what you said you want - a sequence of `Emp` objects, where each has multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a slight change could be usefull: if you change the Email property from a list to string you could group the employees like that:

```
// Group by EmpId
var group = employees.GroupBy(e => e.EmpId);
```

and get the list for a single emp like this:

```
// Example get email List of first emp
group.First().Select(g => g.Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `Emp` class so that `EMail` is a `string` instead of a `List<string>`.

The foreach loop then becomes

```
foreach(string e in r.EMails){
//e holds the EMail
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
var query1 = from emp in employees
                             group emp.Email by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into empgroup
                             select new
                             {
                                 UserId = empgroup.Key.EmpId,
                                 EmployeeType = empgroup.Key.Type,
                                 EmaiIds = empgroup.SelectMany(x => x)
                             };


                foreach (var x in query1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x.UserId);
                    Console.WriteLine(x.EmployeeType);
                    foreach (var emails in x.EmaiIds)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(emails);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Emp> employees= new List<Emp>();
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Email = "one@test.com" }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Email = "two@test.com" }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test", Email = "three@test.com" });  
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test", Email = "four@test.com" }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test", Email = "five@test.com" }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test", Email = "six@test.com" }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 4, Type = "User", Email = "seven@test.com" });  

    var groupedList = from emp in employees
                group emp.Email by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into g
                select new { Key = g.Key, Type = g.Key.Type, Emails = g.ToList() };

    foreach (var result in groupedList)
    {
        //I'm using LINQPad to output the results
        result.Key.EmpId.Dump();
        foreach(var email in result.Emails)
        {
        email.Dump();
        }   
    }

}
public class Emp
{
     public int EmpId { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }             
}
```

My results are:

[image]

or...

```
void Main()
{
    List<Emp> employees= new List<Emp>();
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Emails = new List<string>(){"one@test.com"} }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 1, Type = "User", Emails = new List<string>(){"two@test.com"} }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test",  Emails = new List<string>(){"three@test.com"}  });  
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 2, Type = "Test",  Emails = new List<string>(){"four@test.com"} }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test",  Emails = new List<string>(){"five@test.com"}  }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 3, Type = "Test",  Emails = new List<string>(){"six@test.com"} }); 
    employees.Add(new Emp{ EmpId = 4, Type = "User", Emails = new List<string>(){"seven@test.com"} });  

        var groupedList = from emp in employees
                    group emp.Emails by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into g
                    select new Emp {
                                        EmpId = g.Key.EmpId,
                                        Type = g.Key.Type,
                                        Emails = g.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()
                                    };
        foreach (var result in groupedList)
        {  //I'm using LINQPad to output    
        result.EmpId.Dump();
        result.Emails.ForEach(e => e.Dump());               
        }

}
public class Emp
{
     public int EmpId { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public List<string> Emails { get; set; }             
}
```

My results are also:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks @mjroodt.lets say when grouping, I create a new type other than Emp for example 'Node' with similar structure

Comment: var groupedList = from emp in employees
                    group emp.Emails by new { emp.EmpId, emp.Type } into g
                    select new Node{
                                        NodeId = g.Key.EmpId,
                                        Type = g.Key.Type,
                                        Receipents = g.SelectMany(x => x).ToList() // get error here Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
                                    };

Comment: @sky use Node{ NodeId = g.Key.EmpId, Type = g.Key.Type, Recipients = g.ToList()};

Comment: Thanks last one, sorry, where do I specify order by, I need to order by EmpID. I tried after Select but giving me error